# Running VBA code written in Windows on a Mac

Tags: vba

I've written some VBA to go through a folder and consolidate spreadsheets onto one masterfile.  One of the first things I needed to do was to look for all files in a folder with the extension `.xl*`.

I wrote this on a Windows box, and now someone wants to run this on a Mac.

I have changes the line from

```
Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xl*")
```

to

```
Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xl*")
```

but I get a: run time error 68 - device not available error

How can I get this line running on a Mac?

For reference here is the complete code:

```
Sub Consolidation()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'find last record in mastersheet
 Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")
 Set MyRange = Worksheets("Consolidated").Range("C" & "1")
 lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 
 'looks for files with the follwing extension
 'Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xl*")
 Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xl*")
 
 'cycles through the folder
 Do While Fname <> ""

        If Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & Fname
                
        Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
            Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            n = 0
            m = 0
            'adds recods to the next avaibale row
            'destsheet.Range("B4").Offset(lngLastRow + 1, 1) = originsheet.Range("E4").Value
            destsheet.Range("C" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E4").Value
            destsheet.Range("D" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E5").Value
            destsheet.Range("E" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E6").Value
            destsheet.Range("F" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E7").Value
            destsheet.Range("G" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E8").Value
            destsheet.Range("H" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E9").Value
            destsheet.Range("I" & lngLastRow + 1) = originsheet.Range("E10").Value
            
            lngLastRow = lngLastRow + 1
            wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
 
        End If
        'stips when out of files to import
        Fname = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This reference says that you cannot use wildcards with the Mac `Dir` function:[Ron de Bruin - Loop through Files in Folder on a Mac (Dir for Mac Excel)](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm).

Comment: I'm running MacOS Excel version 16.65 and not having any problems with wildcards in filenames for Dir().  But you do need to explicitly give Excel permission to access your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Files and Folders permission on MacOS Security Preferences pane for Excel.